# Create / Use YUV Image buffer from Camera Preview class

Tags: java, android, camera, yuv

In our application, we need to use capture frame from camera @ 33 fps and pass it to compression before sending it to server,

My compression module can take YUV Image, to compress the image, my camera configuration as follows,

Width = 500 px,
 height = 300 px ,
 Image format : YV12

On the preview callback

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {

                                }
}
```

data size is coming out to be 230400, but i suppose it would be around

500*300(Y) + 500*300/4(U) + 500*300/4(V) i.e. 2250000

i.e. 5400 bytes more, does that mean, i can ignore the reamining one ?

Also i need to create YUVImage object , but stride info is not coming, so how we can create YUVImage from above data.

Sincere Thanks for reading and i really appreciate if anyone can help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Cant help with the data size question but to get YUV from Camera preview you have 2 choices. If running Android 2.2 or later your can use the [android.graphics.YuvImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html#YuvImage%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D%29) class and just pass it's constructor your bytearray from PreviewCallback.

If you need to support pre 2.2 then you need to do something like:

```
/**
 * Decodes YUV frame to a buffer which can be use to create a bitmap.
 * use this for OS < FROYO which has a native YUV decoder
 * decode Y, U, and V values on the YUV 420 buffer described as YCbCr_422_SP by Android 
 * @param rgb the outgoing array of RGB bytes
 * @param fg the incoming frame bytes
 * @param width of source frame
 * @param height of source frame
 * @throws NullPointerException
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
private static void decodeYUV_impl(int[] rgb, byte[] fg, int width, int height) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException 
{
    int sz = width * height;
    if (rgb == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer out is null");
    if (rgb.length < sz)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer out size " + rgb.length
                + " < minimum " + sz);
    if (fg == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer 'fg' is null");

    if (fg.length < sz)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer fg size " + fg.length
                + " < minimum " + sz * 3 / 2);

    int i, j;
    int Y, Cr = 0, Cb = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int pixPtr = j * width;
        final int jDiv2 = j >> 1;
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        Y = fg[pixPtr];
        if (Y < 0)
            Y += 255;
        if ((i & 0x1) != 1) {
            final int cOff = sz + jDiv2 * width + (i >> 1) * 2;
            Cb = fg[cOff];
            if (Cb < 0)
                Cb += 127;
            else
                Cb -= 128;
            Cr = fg[cOff + 1];
            if (Cr < 0)
                Cr += 127;
            else
                Cr -= 128;
        }
        int R = Y + Cr + (Cr >> 2) + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 5);
        if (R < 0)
            R = 0;
        else if (R > 255)
            R = 255;
        int G = Y - (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 4) + (Cb >> 5) - (Cr >> 1)
                + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 4) + (Cr >> 5);
        if (G < 0)
            G = 0;
        else if (G > 255)
            G = 255;
        int B = Y + Cb + (Cb >> 1) + (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 6);
        if (B < 0)
            B = 0;
        else if (B > 255)
            B = 255;
        rgb[pixPtr++] = (0xff000000 + (B << 16) + (G << 8) + R);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, Actually, i need to give YUV data only to my encoder , libvpx, now i have YUV data , so don't want to convert it into the RGB